# How to change NiFi properties on cloudera manager

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudera

I can't locate the configuration directory for NiFi in order to increase heap memory, and it seems cloudera generates a new `process` folder each time I restart Nifi service.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did find an option to add properties in xml file

[image]